# Spatie/Newsletter: MailChimp Invalid MailChimp API key `` supplied in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, newsletter, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Good morning all of you,

I'm currently working on using **spatie/newsletter** in my **laravel 5.6** Blog to work with **MailChimp** to create a newsletter where users can subscribe.

When I try to subscribe, I get this response:

```
 "message": "Invalid MailChimp API key `` supplied.",
 "exception": "Exception",
 "file": 
 "C:\\...\\vendor\\drewm\\mailchimp-api\\src\\MailChimp.php",
 "line": 49,
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Newsletter;
class SubscribeController
{

    public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        if (!filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return "Die eingegebene Email ist nicht gültig.";
        } else {
            if (Newsletter::isSubscribed($request->email)) {
                return "Du bist bereits mit dieser Mail in meiner Mailingliste eingetragen.";
            } else {
                if (!(Newsletter::subscribeOrUpdate($request->email))) {
                    return "Leider gab es ein Problem, bitte versuche es später noch einmal.";
                } else {
                    return "Ihre Email " . $request->email . " wurde zu meiner Mailingliste hinzugefügt.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Env File**

```
MAILCHIMP_APIKEY=123456-us19
MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID=1234567
```

**newsletter.php** (after running 
php artisan vendor:publish -provider="Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterServiceProvider")

```
<?php

return [
    'apiKey' => env('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'),

    'defaultListName' => 'nameOfListInMailChimp',

    'lists' => [
        'subscribers' => [

            'id' => env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID'),
        ],
    ],
    'ssl' => true,

];
```

I have also added the
`Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterServiceProvider::class,`

into the `app/config` providers aswell as

```
'Newsletter' => Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterServiceProvider::class,
```

to the aliases in the `app/config`.

I really don't know why it is not working at this point.

I tried to give all necessary information. Api Key is valid and Status is ok. List Id is valid aswell.

Thank you in advance!
Domi

Comment: line 49 MailChimp.php ?

Comment: Yes, I have added this information a view seconds ago actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself, it took me a while to figure it out.

First: In the `newsletter.php` class, when I configured my lists, I forgot to change the name of the list from `'subsribers'` to `'nameOfListInMailChimp'`.

Second thing I needed to do was:

- `php artisan config:cache`

Because every time you make a change in the .env file, you have to clear the cache to make the changes work.

I hope this is helpful for other people, this basically could be used as a complete How- to-configure Spatie Newsletter ;)

Comment: I had the same problem .. 
running 
` php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked with:

- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ..
running

`php artisan cache:clear`

worked for me